# Why doesn't -moz-background-size:cover work in Firefox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, background-image

I'm coding a site that contains 3 wide images which need to have 100% width at all times. I'm using media queries and I would rather not have to make 3+ copies of each image to make them fit.

This is the CSS I want on the images:

```
#artwork1 {
    width: 1500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(../img/menupic_1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;    
}
```

Here is a jsFiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/RtPEA/. The link just contains the three `<div>`s that need a background that resizes.

I have used `background-size:cover;` on a lot of sites, but in Firefox, it doesn't seem to work on this one.

I have also tried various jQuery plugins. While I did find some that had some success, they did not work on iOS.

Comment: Looks like it's working to me: http://jsfiddle.net/RtPEA/3/. In what way is it not working?

Comment: The image shows, but it doesn't resize.

Comment: It does in the Fiddle I posted (http://jsfiddle.net/RtPEA/3/) my browser (Chrome 23). What browser are you using? Are you looking at the same Fiddle? (I posted a new one because yours didn't have an image in it.)

Comment: Im using Firefox. And yea, i noticed (new to the whole Fiddle thing)

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `background-size` after the prefixed versions:

```
#artwork1 {
    width: 1500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(../img/menupic_1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

- http://jsfiddle.net/RtPEA/5/

[`-moz-background-size` was only supported in Firefox 3.6](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/-moz-background-size), and the other prefixed versions aren't guaranteed to stick around.

Comment: I had no idea the prefixed version even existed. It is also sufficient to state that "you need to add `background-size` after the prefixed versions". There shouldn't be a reason not to use the unprefixed version if it's available. (And that is what's wrong with the use of prefixes as a whole.)

Comment: @BoltClock: good point, answer amended accordingly. Yeah, `-moz-background-cover`'s candle burned but briefly.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite So how do we solve this in Firefox? Is there even a way?

Comment: @71GA: I'm going to blow your mind here: to solve it, we add `background-size` after the prefixed versions.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It didn't work for me. This worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104683/css-background-size-cover-not-working-in-firefox/62533167#answer-62533167

Comment: @71GA: sounds like you were solving a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

The prefixed versions are not necessary.

```
#artwork1 {
    width: 1500px;
    height:500px;
    background-image: url(../img/menupic_1.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;   
    backgroud-size: cover;
}
```

this works in firefox if you also include the meta viewport element in your document head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```