# background-size cover on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, background-image

I'm working on a website, in which I would like a background image to fill up the entire screen, even if part of it is cut off. I found that the `background-size: cover` CSS property works great on Chrome and Safari. However, when I try opening the webpage on Firefox, the entire image looks too high up, with the bottom being the `background-color` that I selected. Why is this going on, and what can I do to prevent this?

Also, I have the `background-position: right center` property, and tried adding the `-moz-background-size` and `-moz-background-position` properties, with no luck.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-moz-background-position: right center;
background-position: right center;
```

EDIT: Here is the website: [crowdsparked.com](http://crowdsparked.com)

Comment: can you show us some of your code please.

Comment: [MDN background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: You don't have a doctype and are in quirks mode. Don't know if that's the reason. Add this to your first line: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. You are required to have it anyway.

Comment: @Rob Added it, but same result. Thanks for trying.

Comment: It’s the `background-position: center center` you have given for the `body#home` element main fault …

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't -moz-background-size:cover work in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720720/why-doesnt-moz-background-sizecover-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

Please try to use this style:

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem - I found that although the background-size is covering the screen, the height of the body was not the whole screen and so when I using the next  50% down from the top, it was positioned far higher than I wanted. When I added width: 100% & height: 100% that fixed it (also margin: 0px to prevent scroll bar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your css:

```
background-size: contain;
//or this:
background-size: cover;
```

You don't need to prefix either of these. Here's the moz spec that explains better than I ever could:

> **Contain**
>
> The contain value specifies that regardless of the size of the containing box, the background image should be scaled so that each side is as large as possible while not exceeding the length of the corresponding side of the container.
>
> **Cover**
>
> The cover value specifies that the background image should be sized so that it is as small as possible while ensuring that both dimensions are greater than or equal to the corresponding size of the container.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Scaling_background_images

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: You're going to have to post more code if you still need help. It's hard to determine the problem otherwise.

Comment: Please see the link I posted on the question.

Comment: Please post the code here in your question or make a fiddle. www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Well build a reduced test case. Gather just the code needed to reproduce the problem and don't post anything else. If you do that I should be able to just copy the code and see the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

that is working in FF