# CSS - background-size: cover; not working in Firefox

Tags: android, html, css, firefox, background-image

```
body{
    background-image: url("./content/site_data/bg.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
```

Check: http://demo.jayantbhawal.in on firefox browsers, NOT in widescreen mode.

The code works on Chrome(Android + PC) and even the stock Android browser, but NOT Firefox(Android + PC). Is there any good alternative to it? Why is it not working anyways? Googled this issue a lot of times, but no one else seems to have this problem. Is it just me? In any case, how do I fix it?
There are quite some questions on SO about it too, but none of them provide a legitimate solution, so can someone just tell me if they have background-size: cover; issues on firefox too?

So basically tell me 3 things:
1. Why is it happening?
2. What is a good alternative to it?
3. Is this happening to you too? On Firefox browsers of course.

Chrome Version 35.0.1916.114 m
Firefox Version 29.0.1

Note: I may already be trying to fix it so at times you may see a totally weird page. Wait a bit and reload.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't -moz-background-size:cover work in Firefox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13720720/why-doesnt-moz-background-sizecover-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]Well it looks alright to me in latest mozilla.

Try using this if you face problems

```
body { 
  background: url("./content/site_data/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
}
```

**Edit**

As some more clearance of answer to OP from comments

```
background: url("./content/site_data/bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
```

Its shorthand for,

```
background-image: url("./content/site_data/bg.jpg");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment:fixed;
```

[Read more here](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

Comment: "Check: http://demo.jayantbhawal.in on firefox browsers, NOT in widescreen mode." That was the first line of my question, after the code.

Comment: It works! It works!
And it works without the prefix though!
But I must ask, why add this, " no-repeat center center fixed; "?

Comment: Its shorthand for, 
`background-image: url(path-to-file/img.jpg);`
`background-repeat:no-repeat;`
`background-position: center center;`
`background-attachment:fixed;`

Comment: Even though it works, I don't understand why firefox needed it and not chrome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55271/discussion-between-gaurav-and-jayant-bhawal).

Answer (score 2):

> 

So I just came across this question because I was having the same problem. It turned out the issue (in my case anyway) was not having

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

at the top of my html file (this only seemed to affect the background-size: cover in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

For Firefox:

```
~$ firefox -v
Mozilla Firefox 68.9.0esr
```

This centers the image...

```
body {
    background-color: #1D4979;
    background-image: url(../images/background-2.png);
    min-height: 100vh;
    min-width: 100vw;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;    
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

background-size was added to Firefox 3.6, however the -moz vendor prefix was required.

use

```
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Safari 3.0 */
     -moz-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 1.9.2 (Firefox 3.6) */
       -o-background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Opera 9.5 */
          background-size: 100% 100%;           /* Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4.0) and other CSS3-compliant browsers */
```

Comment: I did try with prefixes, but I stopped using them, it maybe practice, but I haven't come across any problems not using them in the latest browsers. If I do, i'd use em. But just to be sure, again, I added the prefixes, and nothing happened.
Also, you do realise that using background-size: 100% 100%; for fullscreen image background would basically be a disaster right?
Imagine having a big SQUARE dog face image as a background with background-size: 100% 100%; and use that site on a 16:9 monitor. You get me right?

Answer (score -1):

bhawal,
I think you are using older version of mozilla. Well, this is a common practice to add vendor specific prefixed properties together with W3 standard. We do this just to make sure that it work in most of the browsers.
In your case, you can use the CSS rule below:

```
body { 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Let me know, if this doesn't work; and vote up if it works. :)

Comment: I did try with prefixes, but I stopped using them, it maybe practice, but I haven't come across any problems not using them. If I do, i'd use em. But just to be sure, again, I added the prefixes, and nothing happened.
And I did provide the version of Firefox i'm using.
@Nitesh

Comment: I'm sorry @Nitesh, I didn't notice " no-repeat center center fixed; " this addition, it works though. Thanks! :D
It works without the prefixes too.

Comment: @JayantBhawal I hope you will vote up the answer man. I am sorry I missed the FF version while reading your question.

Comment: Umm, two things.
1. Never ask for a vote up, it's just, weird.
2. I did vote up, cuz it was a correct answer. Someone else voted down it seems.