# Bootstrap background image not show using firefox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

On my html file I'm using:

```
<body style="background-image:url(images/back.png); ">
....
</body>
```

and on my css file:

```
body {

    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  color:#fff;
    background-color:#333;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,Sans-Serif;
}
```

when I open the webpage on google chrome, it works fine, but on firefox the image wont appear. The same thing happen if I call the image from the Css file and not from the html file.

I got more info, when I use the we console in firefox, I get this error:

```
Image corrupt or truncated.
```

Comment: your code works for me already

Comment: I just tried your code in my Firefox browser as well and it appears to be working fine. (Windows 7 64-bit, Firefox 41.0.2).

Comment: are you using an image hosted on the web or in your pc?

Comment: it works only with an online image

Comment: I was testing with an online page and image. Do you have yours online somewhere where we can view it and test?

Comment: no, I was just starting to create it on my pc

Comment: Just tried a quick local webpage with local image using your original code and seems to be working in my Chrome and Firefox properly still.

Comment: are you using bootstrap in the css??

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your body CSS tag.

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center center;
background-attachment: fixed;
```

Comment: Seems to be similar issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104683/css-background-size-cover-not-working-in-firefox

Answer (score 0):

I found this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=941823

Basically large images may cause "Image corrupt or truncated" error on firefox, so I reduce the image to a size of 7494x3891 and it work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

May be your image is currept file.
i try your code to replace one online image and it's work in chrome and firefox too.
check example `[https://jsfiddle.net/wdhzujqn/]`[1](https://jsfiddle.net/wdhzujqn/)

Comment: I post the solution, the image was to big jaja firefox has a bug in that